# Nora alila al bnei adam

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin

I am digging into finding info on the concept of 'Nora alila al bnei adam'.
There seems to be a gemara out there that is connected to this topic and how it somehow relates to the sin of the golden calf and how.

Can someone send me the exact reference , if you know it?
After receivng the reference, I would like to ask more questions and share more about this topic in this forum.

Supposedly, the Gemara in Sanhedrin says "nora alila" is also said on the cheit ha'egel (sin of the golden calf).

I am **not** looking for the reference in Tehillim, but rather in Gemara Sanhedrin.
Ty

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D&tab=text&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance. It doesn't appear in any gemara, although Ben Yehoyada mentions it in his commentary on Gittin https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Gittin.57b.1?vhe=Senlake_edition_2019_based_on_Ben_Yehoyada,_Jerusalem,_1897&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: Where did you read all this? Please add that in.

Comment: @Shmuel I got the first detail from a YT video by Rabbi Alon Anava. He said that Sanhedrin talks about how the sin of the golden calf was more or less a deliberate attempt by the one above to make us sin, for some higher good reason. The rest of the info, I got from google.

Comment: Ah, I'm a big fan of R' Anava, but don't remember it. Good luck!

Comment: @ Shmuel Here he says it at the 44:22 mark...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9cVpX5Qulo&t=2679s

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.31b.27?lang=he&with=all

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.5a?lang=he&with=all

Comment: [This site](https://dailyzohar.com/daily-zohar-2974/) (comment-section) mentions the Toras Chaim of the Mitteler Rebbe of Lubavitch (Rabbi Dovber) where it is supposed to say:  “at times, the evil of the evil inclination overpowers man and he sins [because] from Above they have incited the evil inclination upon him to commit this sin”.

Comment: It's generally brought in connection with Adam and the Tree of Knowledge. Are you asking about the concept in general, or specifically about the Golden Calf?

Comment: @shmosel I am asking about the concept in general. I was fascinated when I read that from Above a person can have the yetzer hara  can be incited etc.

Comment: The idea that people can be "entrapped" into sinning originates in [Tanchuma](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Vayeshev.4.2) with respect to Adam and is elaborated in [Toras Chaim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39393&st=&pgnum=27) by the Mitteler Rebbe (as @Shmuel said). It's a common theme in Chabad Chassidus.